# slideUp() and slideDown() not working inside .delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a website using JQM. I have dynamically created a collapsible via AJAX data. Now, I want to make the collapsible slideup and down smoothly (JQuery mobile). The problem is .delegate function is getting executed, but its using the default sliding speed and not changing. My code is :

```
$('#search-page').delegate('.menu-collapse','expand', function (event) {
      $(this).children().slideDown(300);
  }).delegate('.menu-collapse','collapse', function (event) {
    $(this).children().next().slideUp(300);
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I think some problem with $(this). Can anyone sort it out ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show this in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3pNSx/11/ . Don't mind the bad HTML used. The collapsible is just a simple one now, actually it must come via AJAX.

Comment: Actually, there a few answered questions about animation `collapsible` in jqm: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519391/jquery-mobile-collapsible-slidedown-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try , thats work exactly as you want now

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(event){
    $('[data-role="collapsible"]').bind('expand', function (event) {

        $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-content')
               .css('display','none')
               .slideDown(300, function(){
                  $(this).css('display','block');
                });

    }).bind('collapse', function (event) {  

       $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-content.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed')
              .slideUp(300);    
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3pNSx/40/)

Comment: Its not working. Instead of .on() I want to use .delegate() since the collapsible is dynamically built.

Comment: no no no no man, you animate `li`?? where is reverse animation?

Comment: Thanks @JLP. That worked. But I have one doubt. For a normal collapsible during pagecreate when I run the code mentioned by me above, it runs perfectly. But when I dynamically create a collapsible and use the same, it doesnt work!!.. But the solution given by you work. Can I know why ??

Comment: i think the animation of collapsing dont work if the DOM change dynamically, but display:block/none done, so after collapsing, i force the display to none to repeat correctly the scrollDown on the current DOM ..

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to find way, how you can animate collapsible set, not why `delegate` not working
see questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438588/jquery-mobile-add-animation-to-collapsible-set), and try it out.
But i can't repeat this, because it's bit different.