# How to show a notification bar on Top after n seconds with transition from top to down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In lot of mobile sites, I see notification appear with animation from top to down after some seconds. Currently, I don't remember the sites. I was able to find how to show top notification, but unable to find how to animate this using CSS 3 transition or javscript/jquery. Here is the link which I found, http://www.red-team-design.com/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583942/how-to-delay-jquery-animation

Comment: @Andrew, no I need top notification with animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solve the issue,

```js
/* JAVA SCRIPT */
setTimeout(function () {
$('.notify-bar').show().addClass('notify-bar-height-change');
},2000)
```

```css
/* CSS : */
    .notify-bar{
      background-size: 40px 40px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
        135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
      transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, 
         rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
       transparent 75%, transparent);          
       box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
       width: 100%;
       border: 1px solid;
       color: #fff;
       text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
         background-color: #4ea5cd;
       border-color: #3b8eb5;
         padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .notify-bar-height {
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
        transition: height 0.5s ease;
    }
    .notify-bar-height-change {
        height: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notify-bar notify-bar-height" style="display: none">
    Intall ABC!
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the jquery mobile lib you can use $('#some_selector').slideDown(2000).
hope this helps.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519391/jquery-mobile-collapsible-slidedown-effect)

Comment: @user960567 what am i missing in the question?

Comment: I need to show a top bar notification which will appear in a slide-down fashion.

Comment: What I posted will do just that. You will want to customize how and what you trigger and how you style the element you plan on using it on but the slide down effect is exactly what you see in the example. Sorry if I'm still on the money. If you don't have a good answer when I get home ill hack out a quick example for you.